# Yii CBaseUrlRule - named parameters for controller action

Tags: php, yii

I have a child class that parses urls customly that extends CBaseUrlRule.

The `parseUrl()` function must return a string that is `'controller/action'`, yet what I want to do is to be able to pass named parameters to that action. Is this possible?

For example, a url might be:

`catalogName`/brand/`brandName`/product/`productname`/

What I want is to redirect that path to the Catalog's index action, with that action having:

```
public function actionIndex($catalogName, $brandName, $productName) {
    //do smthng
}
```

I'd make a simple url rule, but then I need the class to process certain information before parsing the url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Named Parameter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-named-parameters) by defing [rules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager#rules-detail) in main.php, like :

```
array(
    'components' => array(
        ......
        'urlManager' => array(
            'urlFormat' => 'path',
            'rules'     => array(
                '<catalogName>/brand/<brandName>/product/<productname>/' => 'catalog/index',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```